# TypeORM makes strange query

Tags: typeorm

I just want to modify data value to "qwer".

But TypeORM makes query like:

```
{
    "sql": "UPDATE table SET data = 0 = 'q', 1 = 'w', 2 = 'e', 3 = 'r' WHERE id IN (1)",

    "code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
    "errno": 1054,
    "sqlMessage": "Unknown column '1' in 'field list'"
}
```

```js
const repository = await connection.getRepository(Table);
const result = await repository.findOne({ where: { id: 1 } });
result.data = "qwer";
await repository.save(result);
```

Comment: How is your `Table` set-up in TypeORM? How is your PK defined?

Comment: id(int) primary generated, data(text)

Comment: result.data = "'qwer'"; worked. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't do anything :S

Comment: OMG it saved as 'qwer'..

Comment: It was not entirely TypeORM, but my mistake. Thank you for trying to help me. :)